# Anything wrong with this way to implement atomic doubles/longs/datetimes/nullables?

Tags: c#, thread-safety, atomic

You can't declare a `double`, `long`, `DateTime`, any nullable or any other structs as `volatile` (it wouldn't work if you could because writes aren't atomic), but in my particular case I need a volatlie, atomically-written `DateTime?`.

I wrote this simple class that ensures that writes are atomic. If you take a copy as below, it will always have either the value from *before* the write or the value from *after* the write, never any incomplete values.

```
/// <summary>
/// A T? where writes are atomic. Implemented as a class (which always has atomic read/writes) containing a readonly value.
/// </summary>
public class AtomicNullable<T> where T: struct {
    public readonly T Value;

    public AtomicNullable(T value) {
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator AtomicNullable<T>(T value) {
        return new AtomicNullable<T>(value);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
private volatile AtomicNullable<DateTime> expiryTime = null;

private bool IsExpired() {
    // Copy of expiry makes sure it doesn't get set from another thread in the middle of evaluating the boolean expression.
    AtomicNullable<DateTime> expiry = this.expiryTime;
    return expiry == null
        || expiry.Value < DateTime.UtcNow;
}


private void Calculate() {
    if (IsExpired()) {
        lock (locker) {
            if (IsExpired()) {
                // do calculation...
                expiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow + MaximumCachedObjectAge;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Two things: first off, I know *you* know this but people reading this might not: *atomic* and *volatile* are not synonyms. The rules of C# ensure that all volatile operations are also atomic, but some atomic operations are not volatile. Second, do you have a good reason to do double-checked locking here? double-checked locking is a dangerous pattern and you should only attempt it if you have evidence that an uncontested lock has an unacceptably high perf cost. Why not just lock the thing and be done with it?

Comment: @Eric: This code is going to run for a lot of users in parallel; if I don't do the check the lock will definitely get contested. It's in one of the only performance-critical sections of my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have reinvented boxing (except with greater type-safety).

```
private volatile object expiryTime = null;

private bool IsExpired()
{
    object expiry = this.expiryTime;
    return expiry == null
        || (DateTime)expiry < DateTime.UtcNow;
}
```

The type-safety thing is nice, though.

These are the things that I would change:

`Calculate()` should be `CalculateIfExpired()` and it should call `Calculate()` to do the real work.

Currently, `Calculate` is messing around with setting the `expiryTime` field. Why should it know how to set `expiryTime` when it doesn't know how to read `expiryTime`? Instead, `IsExpired()` should have a nice, little `SetExpired()` sitting next to it on your tool shelf. And the code should pretend that `expiryTime` is only in scope in those two methods (or make another class so it doesn't have to pretend).

**And now to finally answer your question** :-)

I agree with @Eric Lippert that basic locking is better than double-checked locking unless it is shown to be not good enough. I think the double-checked locking is OK, though, so long as you never forget to mark the controlling variable as `volatile`. All of the problems with this method that I have seen assume that the variable is not volatile.

Comment: Thanks for this. Come to think of it, in my case without volatile there would be no observable bugs; old values of the variable would always cause the log and recheck. But this way I can actually _reason_ about the code and be relatively confident that I know what I'm doing.

Comment: Oh, and this is definitely the same as boxing; but it has expressive power which `(object)` doesn't have.

Comment: @configurator - This is the trouble with this kind of code. You may think there would be no observable bugs, but without `volatile` all kinds of crazy things can happen with multiple threads running on different cores. And now that I look at the code again, I realize that you may still have some bugs. It may be possible for a thread to see an updated version of expiryTime and an outdated (or possibly null) version of whatever "// do calculation" is doing. You may need to rethink this design after all.

Comment: (continued) The calculation appears to rely on the lock to ensure that the memory barriers around the calculation are enforced correctly, but the lock will not come in to play if an updated version of expiryTime is already in the cache for that thread. But the volatile read will probably take care of that. (I'm willing to bet *your* company on it. ;-P )

Comment: In any event, without volatile, it would *definitely* be buggy. The calculations would not be updated on all threads.